# Can I replace static get-only methods with expression-bodied properties without a performance hit?

Tags: c#, properties, configurationmanager

We're currently using `static` methods to retrieve configuration values like this:

```
    public static string Wtrealm()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Wtrealm"];
    }
```

However, I'm not a fan of the "method" look and feel, and I'd much rather use a property, specifically an expression-bodied property:

```
    public static string Wtrealm =>  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Wtrealm"];
```

So basically we'd use `Config.Wtrealm` instead of `Config.Wtrealm()`.

Does this translate into equally performant IL? Or am I introducing a caching issue here?

---

Note that we also use this for connection strings, e.g.:

```
    public static string ConnectionString()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn_string_name"].ConnectionString;
    }
```

And also to retrieve settings that need to be converted before they can be used:

```
    private static readonly Lazy<bool> LazyUseFakeUser =
        new Lazy<bool>(() => ConfigurationHelper.GetBool("UseFakeUser"));

    public static bool UseFakeUser()
    {
        return LazyUseFakeUser.Value;
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're identical... properties are just fields and methods with special names (and some metadata) in IL.

Comment: Properties are implemented using methods under the hood so no, there should be no difference here.

Comment: @JoeSewell properties are just methods, no fields. That's autoimplemented properties (`get; set;`) which are fields and methods with special names.